# Log file Zeroing

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, database-internals

During the creation of the database, I am getting below mentioned information about log file zeroing and I have highlighted my understanding in bold fonts.

```
2015-08-23 12:42:36.850       spid51
 Zeroing C:\...\MSSQL10.SQL2K8ENT\MSSQL\DATA\Instant_Initialization_log.ldf
 from page 0 to 393216 (0x0 to 0xc0000000)
```

**This step is zeroing complete log file**

```
2015-08-23 12:42:48.860       Logon      Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2015-08-23 12:42:48.860       Logon      Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
 Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: ]
2015-08-23 12:43:22.960       spid51
 Zeroing completed on C:\...\MSSQL10.SQL2K8ENT\MSSQL\DATA\Instant_Initialization_log.ldf
2015-08-23 12:43:23.410       spid51     Starting up database 'Instant_Initialization'.
2015-08-23 12:43:23.440       spid51     FixupLogTail(progress)
 zeroing C:\...\MSSQL10.SQL2K8ENT\MSSQL\DATA\Instant_Initialization_log.ldf
from 0x5000 to 0x6000.
```

**This step is zeroing part of the file header (In other words, Boot page of the log file)**

```
2015-08-23 12:43:23.440       spid51
 Zeroing C:\...\MSSQL10.SQL2K8ENT\MSSQL\DATA\Instant_Initialization_log.ldf
 from page 3 to 483 (0x6000 to 0x3c6000)
```

**This step is zeroing unused portion of the most recently written to VLF**

```
2015-08-23 12:43:23.460       spid51
 Zeroing completed on C:\...\MSSQL10.SQL2K8ENT\MSSQL\DATA\Instant_Initialization_log.ldf
```

#### Question

As per below image, the first VLF of log file reflects a page (please refer the `startoffset` value - it is considered as boot page of log file; log file have only one page, known as boot page or log file header page)

[image]

If I follow my understanding and convert the hex value into decimal, it shows from page 2.5 to 3 being initialized as per below calculation.

```
0x5000 = 20480 = 20480 / 8192 (One page size) = 2.5
0x6000= 24576 = 24576 / 8192 (One page size) = 3
```

1. Why is it not showing one page size (24576-20480 = 4096 = .5 page (8192/2=4096))?
2. When log file has only one page as boot page in the log file why it is being initialized from page 2.5 to 3 page instead of page 1 to 2?

Comment: Zero initialization of log file does not occur. Only data file can leverage instant file initialization - meaning it will zero initialize.

Comment: As a fact `Tempdb log file` in certain conditions is Zero initialized at startup. Please see [Jonathans Article](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/does-the-tempdb-log-file-get-zero-initialized-at-startup/)

Comment: TempDB though is the only place where things are 'minimally logged' and no rollback or recovery is promised.  Since SQL Server is an ACID compliant database, I would still consider log files to always be zero'ed out for all intents and purposes when designing and administrating SQL databases.